# Virtualenv - Automate project requirements deployment

Tags: deployment, virtualenv, pip, fabric

I'm using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org) to automate my deployment routines for my projects.

One of them concerns the virtualenv replication.

Automating the installation of new packages is pretty straight forward with

```
local $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
remote $ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Now if I don't need a package anymore, I can simply

```
local $ pip uninstall unused_package
```

But as `pip install` won't remove the packages not present in the requirements anymore,
How can I automate the remove of packages from the virtualenv not present in the requirements ?

I'd like to have a command like:

```
remote $ pip flush -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by keeping the install/uninstall jobs separated.

Install:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Uninstall:

```
pip freeze | grep -v -f requirements.txt - | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just a diff with sets? It might require using a `get` operation though if you're operating on a remote box

On remote

```py
from fabric.api import get, run

run("pip freeze > existing_pkgs.txt")
get("/path/to/existing_pkgs.txt")
```

So now `existing_pkgs` is on your local machine. Assuming you have a new requirements file...

```py
with open("requirements.txt", "r") as req_file:
    req_pkgs = set(req_file.readlines())

with open("existing_pkgs.txt", "r") as existing_pkgs:
    existing = set(existing_pkgs.readlines())
```

Do an operation that gives you the differences in sets

```py
uninstall_these = existing.difference_update(req_pkgs)
```

Then uninstall the pkgs from your remote host

```py
for pkg in uninstall_these:
    run("pip uninstall {}".format(pkg))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be - and I know this is not answering your question perfectly - to use the power of the virtualenv you already have:

It is convenient to have known stable package and application environments, let's say identified by revision control tags, to be able to roll back to a known working combination (this is no replacement for testing or a staging environment, though).

So you could simply setup a new virtual environment ("workon your-tag"), populate it again with "pip install -r" and leave the old behind (for some time, e.g. until the new your-tag release is considered stable) and finally remove the old virtual-env('s).

In your fabfile do something like

```
with cd(stage_dir):
    run("./verify_virtual_env.sh %s" % your-tag)
```

and the "verify_virtual_env.sh" script updates via pip for the given environment.